# Using set of data provided by Service and Interface in Angular to view only selected data in Component

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have created Interface and Service for my test data:

**interface.ts**

```
export interface IColumn {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface IRecords {
  Lp: string;
  id: string;
  pluginName: string;
  port: string;
  Comment: string;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
[...]
import {IColumn, IRecords} from "../interface";

[...]

getColumns(): IColumn[] {
  return [
    { label: 'Lp', value: 'Lp' },
    { label: 'id', value: 'id' },
    { label: 'pluginName', value: 'pluginName' },
    { label: 'port', value: 'port' },
    { label: 'Comment', value: 'Comment' },
  ];
  }

getRecords(): IRecords[] {
  return [
    {
      Lp: '1',
      id: 'gh487',
      pluginName: 'AA',
      port: '8443',
      Comment: 'wahtever',
    },
    {
      Lp: '2',
      id: 'fwe74r743',
      pluginName: 'YY',
      port: '8443',
      Comment: 'some data',
    },
    {
      Lp: '3',
      id: 'fg23748',
      pluginName: 'XYZ',
      port: '8443',
      Comment: 'data',
    },
```

Now i want to view in first component data (and columns) `Lp` `id` `pluginName` and in second component i want to view only `Lp` `id` and `port` data (and columns).

How can i achieve that using the same set of data from service and interface?

**EDIT**

Here is where i view all of data:

**component.html**

```
<p-table
    [columns]="data_columns"
    [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }"
    [value]="data_value"
    dataKey="Lp"
    selectionMode="multiple"
    styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines "
  >
    <ng-template let-data_columns pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of data_columns" class="table-header-style">{{ col.value }}</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-columns="data_columns" let-rowData pTemplate="body">
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of data_columns" class="table-style">{{ rowData[col.label] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

**component.ts**:

```
[...]

export class Component {

  constructor(public HomepageService: HomepageServiceService) {}

  data_columns = this.HomepageService.getColumns()
  data_value: Array<IRecords>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data_value = this.HomepageService.getRecords();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something? please post the code for the attempts that you made and also the issues that you face with that.. Will let people understand the problem better and provide relevant options/help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for these maps like this for example:

```js
getRecordsForComponent1(): IRecords[] {
    return this.records.map(record => ({
        Lp: record.Lp,
        id: record.id,
        pluginName: record.pluginName
    }));
}

getRecordsForComponent2(): IRecords[] {
    return this.records.map(record => ({
        Lp: record.Lp,
        id: record.id,
        port: record.port
    }));
}
```

or also make it more dynamic:

```js
getColumns(columns: string[]): IColumn[] {
    return columns.map(column => ({
        label: column,
        value: column
    }));
}

getRecords(columns: string[]): IRecords[] {
    return this.records.map(record => {
        const newRecord: IRecords = {};
        columns.forEach(column => {
            newRecord[column] = record[column];
        });
        return newRecord;
    });
}

// And then use it like this:
const columnNames = ['Lp', 'id', 'pluginName'];

this.columns = this.dataService.getColumns(columnNames);
this.records = this.dataService.getRecords(columnNames);
```

Comment: shouwld i put ``getRecordsForComponent1()`` in component.ts or in service.ts? then assign it to veriable and iterate through it on html?

Comment: You can put them inside the service but maybe change the name of the methods to be more general.
Then you have a variable inside your component which will be the result of the method and you iterate it inside your html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. This was so simple.

In service i have made additionally two separate column data sets:

```
getRecordsForComponent1(): IColumn[] {
    return [
      { label: 'Lp', value: 'Lp' },
      { label: 'id', value: 'id' },
      { label: 'pluginName', value: 'pluginName' },
    ];
  }

getRecordsForComponent2(): IColumn[] {
    return [
      { label: 'Lp', value: 'Lp' },
      { label: 'id', value: 'id' },
      { label: 'port', value: 'port' },
    ];
  }
```

and even when i load to `data_value` all Records from `getRecords()` i can view only selected columns and value when i load `getRecordsForComponent1()` into `data_columns`  in component.ts.